# How to generate a shuffled number series query with id in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to generate unique 'random' numbers in posgresql.

```
select s
from generate_series(1, 5) as s
order by random();
```

This query results the following:

```
| s |
|---|
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
```

But I would like to append it with an id, like this:

```
| id | s |
|----|---|
|  1 | 2 |
|  2 | 5 |
|  3 | 1 |
|  4 | 3 |
|  5 | 4 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER Function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/).

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS id,
s
FROM generate_series(1, 5) AS s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using your resuly as a FROM (subquery) and ROW_NUMBER () OVER ()

```
select  t.s,  ROW_NUMBER () OVER ()
from  (
  select s
  from generate_series(1, 5) as s
  order by random();
) t
```